# Where to keep common context dependent code between fragment and Activity, except for ViewModel?

Tags: android, oop, mvvm, kotlin, mvp

I am creating this new android application and I am stuck in this thought process. I have an Activity which has a bottom sheet, in which you can choose to pick image from Gallery or Camera to add an attachment to a post. So I need to request permissions, listen for permission callback, parse the gallery/camera results and toggle the UI that's a lot of code. And the thing is I have a fragment which does the exact same thing to upload a profile picture. If it were two activities, I could just add the code to a baseActivity. But its a fragment and an Activity. On the other hand, you should not bloat your ViewModel either and these two components are completely independent.

I have thought of putting it in a ViewModel, but cannot put views in it.
Also, I somehow know that this requirement is a common one.
I am aware of the presenter pattern, but still you cannot put views in it.

```
// starting gallery
private fun startGallery(type: String, title: String, requestCode: Int){
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.type = type
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_PICK
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, title), 
    requestCode)
}

// starting camera intent
private fun startCameraFor(action: String, requestCode: Int) {
    val takeVideoIntent = Intent(action)
    if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(context?.packageManager) != null) 
{
        startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, requestCode)
    }
}

 // Handling image results
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: 
 Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        postViewModel.uploadImageResults(data = data, requestCode = 
        requestCode, userId = "c7c2352b-5449-43bf-a099-688843025130")
    }
    toggleBottomSheet()
}

  // Check for permission
  private fun permissionAction(permission: String =  
  Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, callback: () -> Unit){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        val checkPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context!!, 
        permission)
        if (checkPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity!!, 
            arrayOf(permission), Constants.REQUEST_CODE_STORAGE_PICK)
        } else {
            callback()
        }
    }
}

// Toggles bottom sheet
private fun toggleBottomSheet() {
    if(bottomSheet.state == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
        bottomSheet.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
    } else {
        bottomSheet.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need runtime permissions for `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` (the later as long as you don't have `CAMERA` permission in your manifest).

Comment: The runtime permission is for picking it from storage. Anyways, that is not the question I asked. The question I asked is related to OOPs and structure design.

Comment: You get a URI permission for URIs returned from `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, you don't need the storage permission for those URIs.

Comment: I tested that and yes, one doesn't need the runtime permissions if you use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` indeed. Any thoughts on the problem above? Activity and Fragment having same views and this same code for showing bottom sheet? Is there a way to remove redundancy?